# What is the default access modifier of a class?

Tags: .net, asp.net

What is the default access modifier of a class?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

by Default `Internal` is the access modifier of class

Comment: if it's not a nested class (for nested classes, it's private).

Answer (score 15):

`internal`, if defined directly in the namespace (probably most classes):

> Internal is the default if no access modifier is specified

For classes within other classes, the default is `private`, like class members:

> The access level for class members and struct members, including nested classes and structs, is private by default.

Source: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173121.aspx

Answer (score 5):

An enum has default modifier as **public**

A class has default modifiers as **Internal** . It can declare members (methods etc) with following access modifiers:
public
internal
private
protected internal

An interface has default modifier as **public**

A struct has default modifier as **Internal** and it can declare its members (methods etc) with following access modifiers:
public
internal
private

A methods, fields, and properties has default access modifier as **"Private"** if no modifier is specified.

Answer (score 3):

I believe it's `internal`.

Answer (score 1):

Normally, the accessibility of a member is not greater than the accessibility of the type that contains it. However, a public member of an internal class might be accessible from outside the assembly if the member implements interface methods or overrides virtual methods that are defined in a public base class.

When a member of a class is a property, field, method, event, or delegate, and that member either is a type or has a type as a parameter or return value, the accessibility of the member cannot be greater than the type. For example, you cannot have a public method M that returns a class C unless C is also public. Likewise, you cannot have a protected property of type A if A is declared as private.

Answer (score 1):

`internal`, except for for nested types in which case it is `private`

Answer (score 1):

The default access modifier for a class is `internal` if it's defined within the same namespace. It is `private` if it's defined within another class.